# What is the simplest way of running Hadoop MapReduce in the JVM, with nothing to be installed?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I would like to run MapReduce in a JVM to use multiple cores and to use the Hadoop MapReduce properties of external sorting of the map tasks output that is helping me do a stateful processing in limited (constant) memory consumption.
I am looking for a programatic way that can be replicated anywhere by just running a jar, so either embedded server(s) or just a plain single-JVM version of Hadoop MapReduce so nothing needs to be installed on the computer. Docker is not an option either. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you use Spark or Flink instead. It's very rare you'll find anyone writing plain mapreduce anymore

In Spark, you can use `local[*]` as the "master", and it will use all available cores